# How can I solve removing object that is shared among others

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have this scenario:

```
struct B 
{ 
   A * ptr; 
}

A * a1 = new A1;

b1.ptr = a1
b2.ptr = a1
b3.ptr = a2
```

Now I `delete a1` at some different place, but there are no information about `b` objects.  How can I automatically set:

```
b1.ptr = null 
b2.ptr = null
```

Or how is this mechanism called, so I can "google" some more info.

Comment: I don't know about any existing class doing what you want, but look for smart pointers, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory, maybe `weak_ptr` fits your purpose.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Could you please provide a sample code?

Comment: @MartinPerry - Why not look at the [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: Show us a _valid_ example. What you posted isn't even compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a copy of the example at [cppreference - `std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). It assigns shared pointers to the `B.ptr`s and later checks, if they are still valid. Note that this code doesn't set any `ptr` to `NULL`. Also note that the standard smart pointers require a compiler providing C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {};

struct B {
    std::weak_ptr<A> ptr;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    B b1, b2, b3;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> a1{new A()};
        std::shared_ptr<A> a2{new A()};

        b1.ptr = a1;
        b2.ptr = a1;
        b3.ptr = a2;
    }

    // a1 and a2 don't exist anymore

    auto tmp = b1.ptr.lock();
    if (tmp) {
        std::cout << "Ok to use\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Already deleted\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: Accidental wrong idea removed)

Your fundamental problem seems to be ownership:

Your B struct does not own the A object ( you create it at some other point), and as such it does not know about the A object deletion.

In C++ you have the option to make use of a shared pointer:

```
struct B{
    std::weak_ptr<A> ptr;
}
std::shared_ptr<A> object = std::make_shared<A>();
B.ptr = object;
```

In this case, the weak ptr would be used like

```
if(B.ptr.lock()){
    //Your code here
}
```

This would prevent using the object when it is deallocated with the shared pointer going out of reference.

There is no simple way to notify the struct B that the underlying data has been deleted, as a pointer is simply just a number that stores where an object is allocated. This number has no idea what happens to the object.

Finally, a last option is making some notify() method that notifies all B objects that some A object was deleted, though this would require major reworking and is honestly not the best solution.

I hope it helped :)